# autowiring an external bean does not work

Tags: spring, jsf, autowired

Im tryin to map the bean called "userVO" to the security controller with annotations, it works when I map it by xml configuration, but I keep getting the following error when I use annotations

WARNING: /login.xhtml @22,37 value="#{securityController.userVO.vc_name}": Target unreacheable, 'userVO' returned null

I must say UserVO is in a different project that I also own, and its dependency is handled with maven

The following is my spring-beans config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<import resource="mapper-beans.xml" />


<bean name="userVO" id="userVO" class="rst.core.security.UserVO"
    scope="session" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="rst.core.security" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="rst.controller" />

</beans>
```

The following is the controller with the mapping to userVO that its not working:

```
@ManagedBean 
@RequestScoped
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

 public static Logger log;

 private WebFacade webFacade;

@Autowired
private UserVO userVO;

public SecurityController() {
      log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
      log.debug("Creating SecurityController.");
 }

 public String login() {

    UserVO user= webFacade.validateUser(getUserVO()); // method to search the db
    if (user!= null) {
        return "accessGranted";
    } else {
         return "accessDenied";
    }
}

 //getters and setters....

}
```

Also this is the login screen that triggers the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1      /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <h:head>

  </h:head>

  <h:body>
     <h:form id="form">

    <p:panel id="panel" header="New Person">

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name: *" />
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{securityController.userVO.vc_name}"
                label="name" required="true"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: *" />
            <p:inputText id="password" value="#{securityController.userVO.vc_password}" 
               required="true" label="Password" type="password"/>

           </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Login" update="panel"
            action="#{securityController.login}"/>
    </p:panel>

    </h:form>

    </h:body>
    </html>
```

And the following is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  /web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name>rst-web</display-name>
  <!---+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Spring++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
  <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml
</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
   <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++ JSF +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
       <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is securityController resolved? It is marked with `@ManagedBean` which makes it visible to JSF, on the other hand JSF won't recognize spring's `@Autowired` when instantiating SecurityManager.

If you want to stick to spring, get rid of `@ManagedBean`, change @RequestScoped to @Scope("request") and make sure you have set up ELResolver correctly in faces-config:

```
<faces-config>
  <application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    ...
  </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I remove the '@ManagedBean' annotation, I get the following error instead:
    WARNING: /login.xhtml @22,37 value="#{securityController.userVO.vc_name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'securityController' resolved to null

Comment: This confirms my suspicion you did not configure JSF-spring integration correctly. Please have a look at the rest of the answer.

Comment: oh, but org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver is already configured, if thats what you mean...

Comment: Also, everything works fine when I do the mapping of securityController and userVO with xml

Comment: Spring bean SecurityController is not visible to JSF. Any reason you use @Controller which is a spring-MVC annotation instead of generic @Component? Keep in mind spring-MVC builds its own spring context. You should include web.xml to show a full picture.

Comment: Actually, it should be component as you suggested, but still with the '@Component' annotation I keep getting the error, I just added the web.xml

Comment: It should be fine then - is SecurityController in rst.core.security package?

Comment: No its not, I just added '<context:component-scan base-package="rst.controller" />' should I do something else? Still doesnt work :/

Comment: @pablocmg: You have no clue what you are doing, you have no idea what instantiates your classes and even don't even seem to realize it's crucial. Face it: you are using a technology that is too hard for you. You will not fix it, until you understand it. I hope nobody is paying you for this.

Comment: Enable spring logging (set org.springframework logger to INFO or even DEBUG in log4j config - assuming you use log4j) and make sure config file is read as expected and securityController bean is listed there.

Comment: @mrembisz after enabling debug mode, I noticed that I had  typo in the base-package to scan, after correcting it and applying your other suggestions it finally worked! thank you very much for your help.